# MySQL Query to fill NULL values with GROUP BY HOUR

Tags: mysql

I was searching and couldn't find the answer to
fix my problem.

I want to make a hourly report that i'll get with this query

```
SELECT
HOUR(ce.datetime_entry_queue) hour,
COUNT(ce.id) incoming,
COUNT(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NULL,1,NULL)) dropped,
COUNT(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NOT NULL,1,NULL)) answered
FROM
call_center.call_entry ce
WHERE
ce.datetime_entry_queue>='2014-09-04 15:00:00' AND
ce.id_campaign='1'
GROUP BY HOUR(ce.datetime_entry_queue)
```

This will produce the result that i want. and give me the result as follows

```
|hour|incoming|dropped|answered|
|----|--------|-------|--------|
| 15 |   200  |   2   |   198  |
| 16 |   220  |   10  |   210  |
| 17 |   154  |   0   |   154  |
```

which is fine, but what if there's no calls in 16th hour from 16:00 till 17:00,
I will get the following result.

```
|hour|incoming|dropped|answered|
|----|--------|-------|--------|
| 15 |   200  |   2   |   198  |
| 17 |   154  |   0   |   154  |
```

How can I get the query to return the null values rows as zero values like this

```
|hour|incoming|dropped|answered|
|----|--------|-------|--------|
| 15 |   200  |   2   |   198  |
| 16 |    0   |   0   |    0   |
| 17 |   154  |   0   |   154  |
```

I've tried with creating a table that contains hours ( from 0 - 23 )

```
CREATE TABLE `report_hours` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hour` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=25;
```

Query :

```
SELECT
rh.hour,
COUNT(ce.id) incoming,
COUNT(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NULL,1,0)) dropped,
COUNT(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NOT NULL,1,0)) answered
FROM
call_center.report_hours rh
LEFT JOIN
call_center.call_entry ce
ON
HOUR(ce.datetime_entry_queue)=rh.hour
WHERE
ce.datetime_entry_queue>='2014-09-05 15:00:00' AND
ce.id_campaign='1'
GROUP BY rh.hour
```

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work:

```
SELECT
  rh.hour,
  COUNT(ce.id) incoming,
  COUNT(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NULL,1,NULL)) dropped,
  COUNT(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NOT NULL,1,NULL)) answered
FROM
  call_center.report_hours rh
LEFT JOIN
  call_center.call_entry ce ON
    HOUR(ce.datetime_entry_queue)=rh.hour AND
    ce.datetime_entry_queue>='2014-09-05 15:00:00' AND
    ce.id_campaign='1'
GROUP BY rh.hour
```

Whats wrong with your query:

1. `COUNT(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NULL,1,0))` - counts all rows, to work correctly I change `0` to `NULL`. Also can be changed to: `SUM(IF(ce.datetime_init IS NULL,1,0))`
2. When use `LEFT JOIN table_name` all conditional expressions related to specified table must by under `LEFT JOIN ... ON` clause. If they are under `WHERE` then effectively filters all rows with NULL values (when no match in call_center.call_entry table).

Comment: Glad to hear! Added some explanation.